# surface topography Octave

Tags: matlab, grid, octave, geometry-surface

I am a newbie to Octave, and really struggle with a Matlab script I was given. I am trying to make it run in Octave. The function is defined as

```
 function terrainParameter = calculateTerrainParameter(surfaceTopography,x2,x3,x4).
```

The inputs x2,x3,x4 are clear. What I have troubles with is x1, the surface Topography. In the script follows:

```
latitudeStart = surfaceTopography.xllcorner;
latitudeStep = surfaceTopography.cellsize;
latitudeStop = surfaceTopography.xllcorner + latitudeStep * (surfaceTopography.ncols - 1);

longitudeStart = surfaceTopography.yllcorner;
longitudeStep = - surfaceTopography.cellsize;
longitudeStop = surfaceTopography.yllcorner + latitudeStep * (surfaceTopography.nrows - 1);

[latitudeGrid longitudeGrid] = meshgrid(latitudeStart:latitudeStep:latitudeStop,longitudeStop:longitudeStep:longitudeStart);

altitudeGrid = surfaceTopography.data;
```

Now: the input "surfaceTopography" (=x1), how should that look like? I have an ARC grid (DSM.arc). I managed Octave to read it - without the header (DSM) -and built a 3D mesh. But when I run the script the output reads usually

```
matrix cannot be indexed with .
```

when I try "DSM" or "DSM.arc" as input for "surfaceTopography". Or should the mesh (meshgrid) be the surfaceTopography?

I am not sure my question is clear, but I hope it is and someone can help me here.

Thanks in advance, Peter

Comment: `surfaceTopography` seems to be a structure that contains parameters.  Do you have another function in Octave that reads in surface topography data?  You may need to run a function that will get your data to fit this kind of structure first, then you use this function that you have shown us with that structure as the first parameter

Comment: Hello! 
Thank you. There is unfortunately no function that reads in surface data - only two that use the output of this first function. This structure (surfaceTopography) changes, as it relates to the terrain (digital elevation model) of interest. I wonder if I cannot "tweak" my grids (or xyz) files to fit the structure. I could also export my elevation model as .mat, but then it would still not fit the structure I think.

Comment: So does that mean you are creating the structure by yourself?  Can you show us the code that is doing that?  The reason why I'm asking is because it looks like you are supplying a non-structure as your first parameter when the Octave script is specifically looking for a structure that has certain parameters.

Comment: Hello! No, I am not creating it. What I meant is that this structure is derived from a DEM. But how that should look like, I do not know. I know that a .exe files that was created fron the Matlab code requires a ESRI arc grid. But I understand now the problem. surfaceTopography has a certain structure that is NOT defined in the script.

Comment: I still don't get it.  Can you show us the **full** code?  Basically the code where this function is getting invoked.

Comment: it seems to me that your `surfaceTopography` (x1) is a matrix. However, the piece of code for `calculateTerrainParameter()` seems to expect it to be a struct (Octave's kinda of equivalent to python's dict, perl's hash, or C++ std::map).

Comment: @carandraug: That's what I have been trying to ask the OP: If he is creating the `struct` himself or if there is a function that is doing this for him, but there seems to be some sort of "lost in translation" thing happening.

Comment: Where did you get the `calculateTerrainParameter` function from? Did you find it online? A link would be very useful as I'm sure it will document there how the struct should be constructed

Comment: Hi! Thanks, guys! I appreciate the help. 
I am not creating the required struct. The script starts with  function terrainParameter = [...]. So I think rayreng is correct in the assumption that I need a script/function to built that struct from a DEM (grid). 
The function was given to me from a fellow researcher, but I am not sure I can fully post the code here, as it is his (he is working in the private sector now and tough to get a hold of). 
I looked for documentation in the package, but it is only for the built windows executable

Comment: PS - I also get the error "string cannot be indexed with ." at times. So I think your suspicions are correct

Comment: In this case, you need to create the `struct` yourself.  If you look at the function, you need to create the parameters:  `xllcorner, yllcorner, cellsize, nrows, ncols, data`.  You can do it like this:  `surfaceTopography.xllcorner = ..., surfaceTopography.yllcorner = ..., surfaceTopography.cellsize = ..., surfaceTopography.nrows = ..., surfaceTopography.ncols = ..., surfaceTopography.data = ...` where the `"..."` is what you put in yourself.  Not familiar with this area so can't help you but you can do this yourself.  Once you're done, call your function normally with this as the first param.

Comment: Hello! There is progress - I wrote an executable that defines the xllcorner, yllcorner, etc and then calls the function. It seems to work - now there is a bug with the next next method/function that follows, but that is another story. I am not entirely sure the problem is fixed, but that is defintely the right track. Cheers! Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: As rayreng and carandraug suggested, I needed to create a struct.I did this via a executable I run from terminal (or, alternatively as .m from Octave):

```
    #! /usr/bin/octave -qf
    load DHM
    surfaceTopography.xllcorner = 944452;
    surfaceTopography.yllcorner = 6452389;
    surfaceTopography.cellsize = 1;
    surfaceTopography.nrows = 144;
    surfaceTopography.ncols = 144;
    surfaceTopography.data = DHM; 

    calculateTerrainParameter(surfaceTopography,30,20,7)
```

Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome.  Also make sure you to accept your own answer so it tells us / SO that you have resolved the matter on your own!